# How do I extract only right hand side and left hand side values of "=" operator from a line in text file?

Tags: java

Like for eg., in “int bot = 235;” from a line in text file, I want to extract only “bot” and “235” and store it in a HashMap in Java.

Comment: You need: an in-house data structure, some string parsing magic, and to actually **try**.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have the line available as a ``String``? Take a look at what methods your ``String`` object hast to offer. Show some effort please.

Comment: use your favourite search engine and look for "regular expressions". They might fit your needs

Answer (score 2):

You could use regexp:

```
    String detail = "int bot = 235";
    String pattern = "(\\w+) = (\\w+)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(detail);
    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        result.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

gives

```
{bot=235}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string function `split`, like this:

```
String[] s = string.split("=");
String s1 = string[0]; // "int bot "
String s2 = parts[1]; // " 235;"
```

Comment: ``s2`` also has the semicolon at the end.